# unix for loop modify the output filename

Tags: bash, unix, for-loop

I am working in a directory with file names ending with `fastq.gz`. with using a loop like the following, I will be running a tool.

`for i in`ls`; do if [[ "$i" == *".gz" ]]; then bwa aln ../hg38.fa $i > $i | sed 's/fastq.gz/sai/g'; fi; done`

My question is, I want my output filename to end with .sai instead of fastq.gz with keeping the rest of the filename the same. yet, as it first sees `$i` after `>`, it modifies the input file itself. I tried using it like `<($i | sed 's/fastq.gz/sai/g')` but that does not work either. what is the right way of writing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string replacements to compute the filename and the extension.
Moreover, you shouldn't rely on the `ls` output but loop directly over the expression you are looking for.

```
 for file in *.gz; do
   name="${file%.*}"
   file_output="${name}.sai"
   bwa aln ../hg38.fa ${file} > ${file_output}
 done
```

Comment: this is a very good way and solves my issue, thanks. just out of curiosity, do you also know how to give the preference to sed on $i and get the modified $i as in the question?

Comment: Well I will always do it in several steps since it is a script and you do not need to compess it but you could do:   `CMD > $(echo $file | sed 's/fastq.gz/sai/g') `